# Ubuntu 16.04 - apt-get update - KEYEXPIRED

Tags: apt

I have this error on Ubuntu 16.04 when running apt-get update:

```
Err:15 
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04 Release.gpg
The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1496576244
```

And when I run:

```
apt-key list | grep expired
```

I get:

```
pub   2048R/BEB6D886 2015-03-27 [expired: 2017-06-04]
```

So I try to get the key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keys.gnupg.net BEB6D886
```

And I get:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.oLjKJZ7zza/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys
--keyserver
keys.gnupg.net
BEB6D886
gpg: requesting key BEB6D886 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key BEB6D886: "home:Horst3180 OBS Project 
<home:Horst3180@build.opensuse.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

So nothing has changed, and I still have the same error. Any clue ?

Answer (score 10):

I have the exact same issue (I use Arc theme), and this is more of a workaround. Technically this error is not harmful because it only deprives you of updates of the related software (presumably Arc Theme by Horst3180).

Go to *Settings > Software & Updates > Other Software* and uncheck `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04` like so (see fifth row):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wait for the key owner to create/publish a new key. That's how it works, there is nothing to change, because nothing has changed.

Comment: please elaborate the answer how this is fit the questions

Comment: Do you mean, nothing has changed because there is nothing to change ?

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/793) for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

re-importing the keys:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
```